# Bringing to front QGIS plugin dialog with toolbar icon click

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

Is there a way to bring the already opened QGIS plugin dialog that I wrote to the front with a click on the icon in the QGIS toolbar?

By default, it only opens on click, and to bring it to the front I need to minimize everything in front of it to reaccess the dialog. I haven't made any changes to the default code that the Plugin Builder produced, I only added functionalities that I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `QWidget` method [`activateWindow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.activateWindow) as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12119488/13942740) by [Avaris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843822/avaris).

You can then modify your plugin from this :

```
    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = YourPluginDialog()
        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something
```

To this :

```
    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = YourPluginDialog()
            # show the dialog
            self.dlg.show()
        else:
            self.dlg.activateWindow()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        print(result)
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result == 1:
            # Do something
```

`result` must be equal to 1 because reopening the dialog might give `result` the value of -1, so `if result` is valid. 1 is the outcome when the user is pressing the `OK` button.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works exactly as I needed it to!